cdkDragDrop FROM material dialog to parent
I am trying to create a "clipboard" of array elements that are accessed via matDialog.
I have a "parent component" that consists of n "child components".   Each of theses child components use a mat-table.    I am able to "copy" a row to the clipboard.
Accessing the "clipboard" is a matter of opening a mat-dialog.    I want to be able to "drag" any element from the clipboard into a "child" mat-table.     When I try this, I see that the drop just references the mat-table within dialog rather than the dropzone on the child component.
In the image below, I'm trying to drag from the clipboard to squad 4, post 2......both indexes are 0.....I a little helpo to figure this out.

